# Scala: using Java enums and parameterized functions with valueOf

Tags: java, scala, enums

I'm working on some mixed `Java` / `Scala` code, and since I'm somewhat new to `Scala`, I'm running into an issue that seems that it should be easy to solve, but that has me stumped.

I have a number of enums in Java, and what I'd like to do is write a generic parameterized Scala function that takes a `List[String]` and converts it to a `Set` of enum values:

```
// Not sure if <: is the right operator to say T is a Java enum here.
def strToEnumSet[T <: Enum[T]](values: List[String]): Set[T] =
values.map(x => T.valueOf(x)).toSet
```

This doesn't work, since we can't use `T` as `T.valueOf`, which I understand. I suspect that we have to instead use the `Enum.valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String s)` method. However, I'm not sure the syntax to do this properly.

Do I need to do something like:

```
def strToEnumSet[T <: Enum[T]](cls: Class[T], values: List[String]): Set[T] =
   values.map(x => Enum.valueOf(cls, x)).toSet
```

And if so, what do I pass in for `cls`? Say I have a specific instance I want to call with an `enum` called `MyEnum` and a `List[String]` called `values`:

```
val myEnumSet: Set[MyEnum] = strToEnumSet[MyEnum](???, values)
```

What would I pass in for `???`

Of course, avoiding having to pass in `cls` would be ideal, but I'm not sure that's possible.
Thanks for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

X.java:

```
public enum X {
    a,
    b,
    c
}
```

Test.scala:

```
val a = strToEnumSet(classOf[X], List("a"))
```

**Possible improvement:**

```
def strToEnumSet[T <: Enum[T]](values: Iterable[String])(implicit m: Manifest[T]): Set[T] =
values.map(x => Enum.valueOf(m.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]], x)).toSet
```

You can call it like this:

```
val a = strToEnumSet[X](List("a"))
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I think I need.

Comment: Sorry, Rado. First time using Stack Overflow (other than in google searches), so I wasn't aware of the details of the system. Done - and thank you again!